# My roblox animation wont play with my tool

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

I have an animation script where the tool is supposed to be animated when the player swings it but it doesn't animate.
There are 2 scripts in the tool, a script for a point system and the script for the animation.
I will include both just in case:
Point system:
`--Physical tool related variables
tool = script.Parent
handle = tool:WaitForChild('Handle')

```
--Getting Player
local backpack = tool.Parent
local player = backpack.Parent

--Stats variables
playerStats = player:FindFirstChild('leaderstats')
points = playerStats:FindFirstChild('Points')

onCooldown = false

--Occurs when screen is clicked with tool equipped
tool.Activated:Connect(function()

    if onCooldown == false then
    print('click!')
        --Adding points
    points.Value = points.Value + 1
    
    --Cooldown system
    onCooldown = true
    wait(1)
    onCooldown = false
end
end)`
```

Animation system:

```
`local tool = script.Parent
local panAnim = tool.PanAnim

tool.Activated:Connect(function()
local character = tool.Parent
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild('Humanoid')

local panAnimTrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(panAnim)
panAnimTrack:play()
end)
```

`

I tried the above code and it doesnt work and i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are the creator of the animation. If you aren't the animation will not run.

Comment: I am, I created the animation with a rig and animation editor